# Measure percentage of remote memory accesses

Tags: numa

I'm working in a NUMA machine, with 2 nodes. I'm trying to profile the code to measure what's the percentage of memory accesses to remote memory.

My machine is an AMD Interlagos (Family 15h). Perf support was introduced in Linux 3.9, but I've been having trouble upgrading to kernel versions after 3.8, so at the moment I'm looking at alternatives.

I've had a look at PAPI, but [couldn't figure out how to use a Native Event](http://icl.cs.utk.edu/papi/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=1221&p=2637#p2637).

Answer (score 1):

Try [LIKWID](http://code.google.com/p/likwid/). It comes with a wrapper tool `likwid-perfctr` - just run the code under its control. The `MEM` group of counters is what you need:

```
likwid-perfctr -C 0-11 -g MEM ./executable
```

This would measure using the performance counters on cores from 0 to 11. Adjust to your specific case.